# IBM Watson Studio Notebooks on Safari, sometimes shows `Connection Failed`or `Kernel Dead`

Tags: websocket, safari, jupyter-notebook, data-science-experience, watson-studio

In IBM Watson Studio while using Notebooks (Python, R, Scala) on Safari browser, sometimes the notebook is not connected to the kernel and after several retries shows `Connection Failed`or `Kernel Dead`. Refreshing the browser window does not help. In Chrome and Firefox connection to the kernel for the same Watson Studio notebook works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could happen because of the browser cache. The browser header or cookie could be too long. Cleaning the browser cache should solve it. The following steps show how to clean Safari cache:

1. In the top menu click "Safari"->"Preferences..."
2. In the opened window choose "Privacy" tab
3. Click "Remove All Website Data"
4. In the opened dialog click "Remove now"
5. Refresh the page with opened Watson Studio notebook.

Comment: Thanks, clearing the browser cache resolved the issue.